# Rendering a JSON form using jQuery formbuilder

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, coldfusion, formbuilder

I want to use jQuery formbuilder (https://formbuilder.online/docs/) and want to render the JSON form generated by Formbuilder on my web page.

Can someone help to show how I can achieve this with ColdFusion?

Here is sample of the JSON generated by Formbuilder:

```
[
    {
        "type": "date",
        "label": "Date Field",
        "className": "form-control",
        "name": "date-1502794115227"
    },
    {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "Button",
        "subtype": "button",
        "className": "btn-default btn",
        "name": "button-1502794117421",
        "style": "default"
    }
]
```

How do I display the form on the page? I am not familiar with JSON. It would be ideal if I could deserialize the JSON and return actual HTML source.

The JSON is displayed by Formbuilder but I also do not know how to get the JSON into a ColdFusion structure or variable that I can use. Any ideas?

Comment: ColdFusion doesn't come into the equation until you submit the form.

Comment: As @DanBracuk mentioned, what you have asked so far has nothing to do with ColdFusion. It is all jQuery and the formbuilder plugin. As it states on the link you provided - _jQuery formBuilder is a 100% client-side plugin_ ColdFusion runs server-side. There are lots of demos and example code included in that documentation link as well. Go through those demos and then come back and ask a more specific question if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me explain more.
I want to use the form builder and then publish the HTML Form. I need the actual rendered form source. I do not know how to get the form source from what is produced by the form builder.

Comment: You don't even have the form on the page?  I suggest you go back to the FormBuilder page and read the Getting Started section.  This is an HTML/CSS/javascript+jQuery issue you're having.  ColdFusion will only be involved once you get the form on the page and submit it.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments on your question suggest, the JSON output that's giving you is just a preview of how the form structure will look.

### Step 1: Save the Form Structure

You need to first hook an action on the 'Save' button to save this structure to your database. Using **jQuery**, this will look something like the following (assuming your formBuilder will be in an element with attribute `id="form-builder"`). *Put this in a JS file loaded in your form builder page*:

```
// Initialise the form builder
var fb = $( '#form-builder' ).formBuilder();

// Post the data to a script which will save it to your db
$( '.save-template' ).on( 'click', function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save-form.cfm', // Point this to the file you create to save data
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            formStructure: JSON.stringify( fb.actions.getData('json') )
        },
        success: function( response ){

            // Got a response
            console.log( 'Response from the save action: ' + response );

        },
        error: function( jqXHR ){

            // Something went wrong
            console.log( 'Error saving the form (details below)' );
            console.log( jqXHR );

        }

    });

}
```

Then in CF, use [deserialiseJSON](https://cfdocs.org/deserializejson).

**save-form.cfm - tag syntax**

```
<!--- Converts JSON string to CF ARRAY (not struct - the JSON is an array of fields) --->
<cfset formStructure = deserializeJSON( form.formStructure ) />
```

**save-form.cfm - script syntax**

```
// Converts JSON string to CF ARRAY (not struct - the JSON is an array of fields)
formStructure = deserializeJSON( form.formStructure );
```

Then loop through the array (again, note that the formBuilder JSON is output as an array of fields, not a struct) operating as you wish and insert the form structure to your db (either in JSON format to cut out the deserialising and looping or as individual fields using relational DB work).

### Step 2: Load the form for the user

This is a lot more complex than you think - I was recently working with this and ended up rewriting the whole formRender library to better suit our needs.

I'd recommend if you're not familiar with this kind of approach then just load in formRender.js (provided with form builder installation) and read the docs (eh?) about that.

If, on the other hand, you want to individually parse the fields like I did, then you can loop through the array, taking each field (which will be a struct) and outputting markup depending on what you find. I'd show you some of what I did, but it's a library of functions which call each other and this answer would end up being way too long!

Hope this helps you on your way somewhat

JC